# preg_match_all fails if first or last letter is in utf8

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, pcre

Probleme starts when i search words in string which starts/ends with utf-8 character - it cant find the match. If word starts/ends with none utf-8 character then all works fine.
The code:

```
$str= 'String: ābols, abols, abŌls, abōls, aboļŠ, aboĻs';
$find = array('ābols', 'abols', 'abōls', 'aboļš', 'aboļs');
preg_match_all("/(*UTF8)\b(" . implode($find,"|") . ")\b/i",  $str, $matches);
```

In result you can see - "words" which starts with utf-8 character cant be found: 
Image to result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZku3.png

What i`m doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you don't see words that begins (or finish) with an "utf-8" character is simple: `\b` is a word boundary that is by default a limit between a character from (and only from) `\w` (or `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) and another character.

To change the behaviour of `\b` (to get it works with all numbers and all letters of the galaxy), you must use the u modifier. With this modifier `\w` contains now all letters and all numbers:

```
preg_match_all("/(*UTF8)\b(" . implode($find,"|") . ")\b/iu",  $str, $matches);
```

another way is to replace word boundaries with lookarounds:

```
preg_match_all("/(*UTF8)(?<=^|[\s\pP])(" . implode($find,"|") . ")(?=[\s\pP]|$)/i",  $str, $matches);
```

Comment: @user3101318: Ok, in this case you must check the answer as accepted.